# Difference between שֵׁבֶט and מַטֶּה

Tags: words, commentaries

I wondered if there is a difference between the words שֵׁבֶט (rod, stick, staff) and מַטֶּה (rod, stick, staff) in matter of function, symbolism, and 'spiritual meaning'? A mateh seems almost like a magical wand, for Moshe used it to perform miracles and fight off Amalek, so I figured out that there must be some symbolism or deeper meaning to it.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/84099

Comment: @msh210: I'm not asking about the tribes, but about in regard with the literal meanings of these words like when Moshe had to take the staff of G-d to perform miracles or as a tool to herd (like in Vayikra 27:32) or a stick to walk with (מַקֵּל Exodus 12:11 or to hit someone with (Shemot 21:20/Mishlei 29:15) or as a scepter (Zecharya 10:11).

Comment: or like the Shemot 21:19 *(Ezekiel 29:6) משענת

Comment: There is an essay about this in FrameWorks Bamidbar (R. Matis Weinberg) on the Sidra of Matot/Masei, called "Ethnicity and Nationhood".

Comment: @Chaim; is that available online?

Comment: @user4762 the essay is available for purchase here: http://www.lulu.com/shop/rav-matis-weinberg/frameworks-journal-42-43-matot-masei/ebook/product-22801215.html

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/44034/what-is-the-significance-of-using-shevet-vs-mattot-in-parshat-mattot

Comment: http://www.balashon.com/2020/05/shevet-and-matteh.html

Answer (score 1):

The Radak in [Sefer HaShorashim](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5a/%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%9D.pdf) (see p. 245) on the root שבט seems to use the two words interchangeably but he does write -

> "*ונקרא הראש והמושל שבט כי דרך המושל לחיות שבט בידו ועוד כי בידו שבט מוסר העם שבט מושלים*"
>
> "*And he is called the head and the leader of the tribe because it is the way of a ruler to live with a stick ('shevet') in his hand, and furthermore, because a stick in his hand rebukes the people - a stick of rulers.*"

Interestingly though as far as the function of hitting, the Malbim points out a crucial difference based on the Pasuk in [Yeshaya 10:24](https://www.sefaria.org/Isaiah.10.24?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> לָכֵ֗ן כֹּֽה־אָמַ֞ר אֲדֹנָ֤י יְהוִה֙ צְבָא֔וֹת אַל־תִּירָ֥א עַמִּ֛י יֹשֵׁ֥ב צִיּ֖וֹן מֵֽאַשּׁ֑וּר **בַּשֵּׁ֣בֶט** יַכֶּ֔כָּה **וּמַטֵּ֥הוּ** יִשָּֽׂא־עָלֶ֖יךָ בְּדֶ֥רֶךְ מִצְרָֽיִם׃
>
> *Assuredly, thus said my Lord God of Hosts: “O My people that dwells in Zion, have no fear of Assyria, who beats you with a **rod** and wields his **staff** over you as did the Egyptians.*
>
> (Sefaria translation)

The [Malbim](https://www.sefaria.org/Isaiah.10.24?lang=bi&p2=Malbim_on_Isaiah.10.24.1&lang2=bi) notes that one only strikes with a 'shevet' as using such an implement is not dangerous whereas using a 'mateh' is dangerous and this is what was used when fighting the King of Cush.

Comment: Another relevant verse (and commentary of Malbim ad loc) is [ibid. 28:27](https://www.sefaria.org/Isaiah.28.27?lang=he&with=Malbim%20Beur%20Hamilot&lang2=he), כִּי בַמַּטֶּה יֵחָבֶט קֶצַח וְכַמֹּן בַּשָּׁבֶט. He explains that כמון (cumin) needs only the weaker שבט, while קצח (black cumin) needs the harder מטה.

Comment: Nice! Yasher Kochacho!

Answer (score 0):

I touched on this question in [this](https://ohr.edu/7444) essay:

> The Vilna Gaon (1720-1797) writes that both a mateh and shevet are
>   using for hitting, but differ slightly: to hit with a mateh one only
>   needs to raise one’s hand a bit in order for the impact to be felt,
>   while to hit with a shevet one must wind up one’s hit with energy for
>   the impact to be felt... Rabbi Wertheimer... also explains that mateh and makel are only made from wood, while shevet can be made from wood or metal (see Psalms 2:9 which refers to an iron shevet)...
>
> Citing an explanation from Rabbi Shmuel Dovid Luzzatto (1800-1865),
>   Rabbi Yaakov Tzvi Mecklenburg (1785-1865) writes that the words shevet
>   and mateh actually have different meanings, but because they are
>   conceptually related they became interchangeable. He explains that the
>   word shevet originally referred to the leader of a tribe, while mateh
>   originally referred to the other members of a tribe. The leader of a
>   tribe is similar to a mast upon which a flag is mounted because all of
>   the members of the tribe rally around the leader. In this way the word
>   for a leader of a tribe is homonymous with the word for stick. Since
>   all the members of a tribe are united behind their leader, references
>   to them can be subsumed under the word used for the leader. Thus, the
>   word shevet also came to mean members of a tribe because the leader of
>   the tribe embodies the entire tribe itself. In terms of sticks, he
>   argues that shevet and mateh can both refer to the exact same type of
>   stick, but they refer to different parts of the stick. The word shevet
>   refers to the top of the stick (just as the leader sits atop the
>   hierarchal structure of a tribe), while the word mateh — seemingly
>   related to the Hebrew word lematah (underneath) — refers to its bottom
>   (just as the other members of the tribe live under the leadership of
>   their clan chief).
>
> Malbim (to Gen. 49:28) writes that the word shevet does not literally
>   mean “stick”, rather it means “branch,” which was the most common item
>   used as a stick. Based on this, he explains that shevet means branch
>   and tribe because each of the Tribes of Israel is simply a branch of
>   the greater family tree of Jacob’s descendants.

SOURCE: [What's in a Word?](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/whats-in-a-word), "Tribesmen Stick Together"