# Israelite/Jewish flags

Tags: sources-mekorot, history, talmud-gemara, northern-kingdom

Does the Talmud or any other Jewish sources for that matter discuss and/or describe any flags that were associated with ancient Israelite/Jewish kingdoms?

Comment: https://boulderjewishnews.org/2017/flags-of-love-and-war-parashat-bamidbar/

Comment: Did flags (as we know them) exist back then?

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/89499

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/23510/7539

Comment: @DoubleAA There were flags in the midbar. It's not a stretch to suggest that other - ahem - _autonomous collectives_ would have their own banners as well.

Comment: @Yehuda were there flags (as we know them) back then?

Comment: @DoubleAA Based on [Rashi to Bamidbar 2:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Numbers.2.2.1), it certainly sounds like it.

Comment: @Yehuda flags weren't invented yet...

Comment: @DoubleAA Rashi describes it as a colored piece of cloth with a picture on it. If that's not at least a loose definition of a flag, I don't know what is.

Comment: @Yehuda Rashi lived in the 11th century

Comment: @DoubleAA Rashi was describing what the pasuk itself says happened in the midbar. I don't think the standard for this site is to assume that Rashi invents things out of whole cloth (pun intended).

Comment: @Yehuda of course it isn't, Rashi is just quoting a midrash

Comment: @DoubleAA So if Rashi is quoting a Talmud-era source in the midrash that there were flags (as we know them) in the midbar, then is stands to reason that - at least according to the Talmudic sources OP is asking for - it is not anachronistic to assume that there were flags in the time of the ancient Israelite/Jewish kingdoms.

Comment: @Yehuda Well, it's anachronistic to assume there were flags then, but I guess it's not anachronistic to ask what the Talmud anachronistically thought of those 'flags'.